# Add a foreign key to composite primary key and changes in JPA Entity class

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, eclipselink, many-to-one

I have a class User with primary key (id) which corresponds to 'user' table in SQL Server database. My User class has a many to one relationship with Project Entity.

```
  public class User{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "project", referencedColumnName = "id_project")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Project project;
    }
```

database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(27,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar](45) NULL,
    [project] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_user_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [id] ASC)
```

Now in my database I need to have two rows with same user ids but different projects so I changed my primary key to a composite primary key in my user table.

```
   user table:        id  name  id_project
                    ---------------------------
                       1   John      5
                       1   John      6

   project table:     id    name  
                    ---------------
                       5   Project5     
                       6   Project6
```

and changed my table like this

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user](
        [id] [int] IDENTITY(27,1) NOT NULL,
        [name] [varchar](45) NULL,
        [project] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_user_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [id] ASC,
    [project_mode] ASC)
```

My question is that: Was this step required in my table? and if it was, then how can I change the @id of my User class?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me, as what are you going to expect back when you search for a particular 'user'?  Wouldn't the table make more sense if you normalized the User table into separate User and User_projects relation table?  Then it would be a simple M:M relationship between User and projects.  Sequencing will not work in the single User table case, as it should prevent ever reusing ID values - User "John" with two projects is going to have two unique IDs assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA 2.1 allows derived IDs, allowing you to mark relationships as being part of the ID.  User would look like this:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(UserPK.class)
public class User{
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "project", referencedColumnName = "id_project")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Project project;
}

public class UserPK{
    private Integer id;
    private Integer project;//use the same type as the Project's ID.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd seriously recommend to have a look at the normal forms of relational databases. Especially the [Third Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

In this case I'd keep the table `user` without the column `id_project`. Instead you can create a third table `user_project` with the column `id_user` and `id_project`, both part of the primary key. This is the usual way to model an `n:m` relationship in a relational database.